# Filter by a nested jsonb array column against the array of the same signature

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-11, cross-join, postgresql-json

I have the attendee table that has a `jsonb` array field called `eventfilters`.

Given the query filter array of the same signature (form) as the `eventfilters`, I need to select the attendees filtered against this `eventfilters` field by a query filter value.

---

Below is the example of both the query filter and `eventfilters` field:

The `eventfilters` field looks like:

```json
[
    {
      "field": "Org Type",
      "selected": ["B2C", "Both", "Nonprofit"]
    },
    {
      "field": "Job Role",
      "selected": ["Customer Experience", "Digital Marketing"]
    },
    {
      "field": "Industry Sector",
      "selected": ["Advertising", "Construction / Development"]
    }
]
```

The query filter can look like this:

```json
[
    {
      "field": "Org Type",
      "selected": ["B2C", "Nonprofit"]
    },
    {
      "field": "Industry Sector",
      "selected": ["Advertising"]
    }
]
```

So, both the `eventfilters` field and the query filter are always of the same signature:

```
Array<{"field": text, "selected": text[]}>
```

---

Given the query filter and `eventfilters` from the above, the filtering logic would be the following:

- Select all attendees that have the `eventfilters` field such that:

  - the `selected` array with the `field: "Org Type"` of the attendee (`eventfilters`) contains any of the values that are present in the `selected` array with the field "Org Type" of the query filter;
    **and**
  - the `selected` array with the `field: "Industry Sector"` of the attendee (`eventfilters`) contains any of the values that are present in the `selected` array with the field "Industry Sector" of the query filter.

The query filter array can be of different length and have different elements, but always with the same signature (form).

---

What I could come up with is the logic stated above but not with the `and` for each element in the query filter, but with the `or`:

```sql
select distinct attendee.id,
                attendee.email,
                attendee.eventfilters
from attendee cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(attendee.eventfilters) single_filter
where (
    ((single_filter ->> 'field')::text = 'Org Type' and (single_filter ->> 'selected')::jsonb ?| array ['B2C', 'Nonprofit'])
    or ((single_filter ->> 'field')::text = 'Industry Sector' and (single_filter ->> 'selected')::jsonb ?| array ['Advertising'])
);
```

Basically I need to change that `or` in the `where` clause in the query above to `and`, but this, obviously, will not work.

The `where` clause will be generated dynamically.

Here's the example of how I generate it now (it's javascript, but I hope you can grasp the idea):

```js
  function buildEventFiltersWhereSql(eventFilters) {
    return eventFilters.map((filter) => {
      const selectedArray = filter.selected.map((s) => `'${s}'`).join(', ');
      return `((single_filter ->> 'field')::text = '${filter.field}' and (single_filter ->> 'selected')::jsonb ?| array[${selectedArray}])`;
    }).join('\nor ');
  }
```

---

The simple swap of `or` and `and` in logic seems very different in the implementation. I guess it would be easier to implement it with the use of `jsonpath`, but my postgres version is 11 :(

How can I implement such filtering?

---

PS: `create table` and `insert` code for reproducing: https://pastebin.com/1tsHyJV0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I poked around a little bit and got the following query:

```sql
with unnested_filters as (
    select distinct attendee.id,
                    jsonb_agg((single_filter ->> 'selected')::jsonb) filter (where (single_filter ->> 'field')::text = 'Org Type') over (partition by attendee.id) as "Org Type",
                    jsonb_agg((single_filter ->> 'selected')::jsonb) filter (where (single_filter ->> 'field')::text = 'Industry Sector') over (partition by attendee.id) as "Industry Sector",
                    attendee.email,
                    attendee.eventid,
                    attendee.eventfilters
    from attendee
             cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(attendee.eventfilters) single_filter
    where eventid = 1
) select * from unnested_filters where (
    (unnested_filters."Org Type" #>> '{0}')::jsonb ?| array['B2C', 'Both', 'Nonprofit']
    and (unnested_filters."Industry Sector" #>> '{0}')::jsonb ?| array['Advertising']
);
```

It's a bit weird, especially the part with `jsonb_agg`, but seems like it works.